# Choose any one of the output using NSPrediccate

Tags: ios, swift, ui-automation

When I run below step in XCode UI Test. I am getting multiple outputs.

```
print(collectionViews.staticTexts.element(matching: NSPredicate(format: "(%@ IN identifiers), "price")).debugDescription)
```

**Output:**

```
Find: Elements matching predicate '"price" IN identifiers'
          Output: {
            StaticText 0x608000375f00: traits: 8589934656, {{24.0, 384.0}, {197.0, 27.5}}, identifier: 'price', label: '123'
            StaticText 0x6080003768c0: traits: 8589934656, {{24.0, 762.0}, {197.0, 27.5}}, identifier: 'price', label: '456'
          }
```

Is there anyway I can get single output instead of multiple outputs using swift. I am trying to print **label** which is **123**.

Output I am looking for:**123**

**Note:** Label value keeps on changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the element during test then you could define accessibilityIdentifier based on index path and then use that in your uiautomation test to get the element.

e.g.:

```
// suppose label has traits of a button
label.accessibilityIdentifier = "<some constant>:\(indexPath.row)"

// test class
let label = table.buttons["<some constant>:\(<row index>)"] //this will give u only one element
label.tap()
```